# JS execute regular expression within certain timeframe

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to execute a regular expression within certain timeframe? For example, we execute regex r and we wait for it to finish maximum 5 seconds, otherwise we cancel. Is this something anyone has experience with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not quite sure what you mean by "execute", but in certain cases it's possible to turn a blocking operation into a loop:

```
s = "long thing"
re = /[a-z]/g

// blocks
matches = s.match(re)

// doesn't block
matches = []
while(m = re.exec(s)) {
 matches.push(m[0])
 do your time check here
}
```

Comment: How is the second example non-blocking? I thought `re.exec(s)` would evaluate the entire `s` string in one call, effectively meaning your `while` loop will only execute once. But I could be wrong.

Comment: In fact, scrap that - I now see what you mean. However, this would surely only work if the time between matches was less than 5 seconds - i.e. the code inside the `while` loop only executes when a match occurs, and if more than 5 seconds pass between matches, the code blocks until the next match is found. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks, that's a fair point - and obviously browser support for Web Workers is limited whereas your solution uses the native language capabilities of Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could think of right now would be to run the Regex in a separate thread using the [WebWorkers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_web_workers), and using a timer in the main thread to signify 'timeout' and kill the worker thread using `myTimer.terminate();` syntax. However, this brings a whole load of problems to the table, as the worker thread does not have any access to the DOM and acts purely like a simple message bus.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating a regular expression in JavaScript is a blocking operation so you don't have a chance to time and cancel its execution. A possible solution would be using [web workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers) - but I don't have any experience with those.